# How can I test for two field values in an SSRS Textbox's Expression property?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I successfully use this Expression in a Textbox:

```
=IIF((Fields!Week.Value="WK1"),Fields!Price.Value,"")
```

I need to be more granular, though - not only am I looking for a Week value of "WK1" for this particular column before assigning it the value of the Price field, but also based on the value of the Unit field.

So I would expect an expression like this to work:

```
=IIF((Fields!Week.Value="WK1" && Fields!Unit.Value="Rock Bottom"),Fields!Price.Value,"")
```

...or else this:

```
=IIF(((Fields!Week.Value="WK1") && (Fields!Unit.Value="Rock Bottom")),Fields!Price.Value,"")
```

...but when I try previewing the results after either of those, I get, "*The report preview failed because the report could not be built. Read the errors, warnings, and messages in the Error List window for specific build failures.*"

That message is:

> [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘TextboxCraftworksPriceWk1Data.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an
>   error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

So it says an expression is expected; how are those expressions not expressions?

Now I've got John Mellencamp's "*Without Expression*" tune zipping through my mind's ears.

Comment: Try using `AND` instead of `&&`, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255271.aspx).

Comment: Yep, it "works" now (doesn't return any data for that column, but at least it runs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>From [Expression Reference (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240847.aspx)</sup>
> *Expressions must have valid **Visual Basic syntax** before a report can be published or processed.*

With that in mind you should be using [logical `And` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255271.aspx) as [@alejandro-zuleta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2647648/alejandro-zuleta) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602273/how-can-i-test-for-two-field-values-in-an-ssrs-textboxs-expression-property/37602573#comment62689416_37602273).

```vb
=IIF((Fields!Week.Value="WK1" And Fields!Unit.Value="Rock Bottom"), Fields!Price.Value, "")
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [SSRS Expressions: Part 1 - Program Flow](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24959.ssrs-expressions-part-1-program-flow.aspx)
- [Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)